# Creating a Dice Game in C Program, but I can't get the points to print out correctly

Tags: c

The problem is in the functions as when the Round Type is "Bonus" it is supposed to print 200 points but it doesn't and instead prints out the else if of roundtype "Double"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

enum ROUNDTYPE{ Bonus, Double, Regular};

// Generates a psuedo random number with parameters of max and min
int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{   
    //  start random number generation
    srand(time(0));
    //  random number of determined max and min
    int rndmNum = (rand() % max) + min;
    return rndmNum;
}
// Will determine the type of Round that will take place
enum ROUNDTYPE getRoundType()
{   
    // declaring roundtype
    enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype; 
    // random number of 1-10
    int max = 10;
    int min = 1;

    int rT = (getRandomNumber(min, max));
    // conditionals for roundtype

    if (rT <= 2)
    {   
        // Bonus: replace “points” to be equal to 200 as calculated above using a random number generator.
        roundtype = Bonus; 
        printf("\nType    : Bonus");
    }
    else if (rT >= 3 && rT <= 5)
    {   
        // Double: update “points” to be equal to DOUBLE the number of points 
        roundtype = Double; 
        printf("\nType    : Double");
    }
    else if (rT >= 5 && rT <= 10)
    {   
        // Regular: keep the “points” equal to the number of points as calculated above using a random number generator.
        roundtype = Regular; 
        printf("\nType    : Regular");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError");
    }
}

int getRoundPoints(enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype)
{   
    // points variable
    int points;
    // conditionals to calculate points by roundtype
    if (roundtype = Bonus)
    {
        // print out points (10 - 100) in multiples of 10
        points = 200;
    }
    else if (roundtype = Double)
    {
        points = (((rand() % 10) + 1) * 20);    
    }
    else if (roundtype = Regular)
    {
        points = (((rand() % 10) + 1) * 10);
    }
    printf("\nPoints  : %d", points);
}
/*
void printPlayerPoints( int p1, int p2)
{

}

void printRoundInfo( ROUNDTYPE t, int dice, int points)
{

}
*/
int main()
{   
    
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    printf("%d", getRandomNumber(min, max));
    //getRoundType();
    getRoundPoints(getRoundType());


    return 0;
}`
```

The problem is in the functions as when the Round Type is "Bonus" it is supposed to print 200 points but it doesn't and instead prints out the else if of roundtype "Double"

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the output as you can see if doesn't follow the conditional if statements:

[image]

I believe I am not correctly calling the ROUNDTYPE function to give that information to the getRoundPoints function

Comment: in  C for checking use == (is equal operator) instead of = (assignment)
for the if part in getRoundPoints function

Comment: Each time you call `getRandomNumber` with the same min/max, it will return the same value.  Do you see why? (hint: call srand from main)

Comment: nit: `int rndmNum = (rand() % max) + min;` is technically a bug, but just happens to work with `min==1`. You really want `int rndmNum = (rand() % (max-min+1)) + min;`

Comment: Thanks for all the input I went and changed the == (is equal operator) for the if part in getRoundPoints function as well as suggestion for moving srand to main and the way to write int rndmNum. Unfortunately I am only get 10 for my points value and I am unaware why.

Comment: @Juggs Why is `rT == 5` acceptable to both `else if (rT >= 3 && rT <= 5)` and `else if (rT >= 5 && rT <= 10)`?  `else if (rT <= 5)` ... `else` makes more sense.

Comment: NEVER change the original code in your question when you EDIT. Instead, ADD the new code below your original. WHY? When you modify the original code in your question ALL comments and answers provided BEFORE the edit no longer make sense to any future visitors to this page. You have created an *anachronism*. (you are new, so you get a *Free Pass* on this one -- but going forward -- don't do that)

Comment: @chux Thanks for the suggestion I usually create my code to work and then slowly clean it up once I do and since I am stumped rn I haven't yet

Comment: @Juggs Better to clean-up all you can before posting.

Comment: @David my bad I am new to the site and this my first time asking a question, so I was looking for a way to continue adding my updated work. Where can I find how to add my update code for further help? I also reversed the post to the original so others can see as well

Comment: No worries. That's why I added the (...) to the comment. As long as you see now how that confuses things, you are good going forward `:)`

Comment: Enable warnings when you compile (If your are using gcc or clang, use `-Wall` `-Wextra` `-Wpedantic`), and try to fix this errors or be sure you want to ignore them and they don't warn about something that actually causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

The result of your randomizing between `min` and `max` should be:

```
int rndmNum = rand() % (max - min + 1);
return min + rndmNum;
```

This does not consider negative numbers though.

The main error is using `=` (assignment) for the comparison `==`. In C a weak point, and often one sees the following coding convention: constant first. That prevents an unintended assignment/typo.

```
if (Double == roundtype)
```

Compile always with a larger warning level as C is notorious in accepting unintended constructs. (Or start with a high level programming language.)

Comment: If the OP is calling `getRandomNumber(1,6)` to simulate a dice roll, it should probably be: `int rndmNum = (rand() % (max-min+1)) + min;`

Comment: @selbie corrected `+1`. I also would have made one expression (without variable even), but thought to be more clear. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "dicegame.h"


enum ROUNDTYPE{ Bonus, Double, Regular};

// Generates a psuedo random number with parameters of max and min
int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{   
    //  random number of determined max and min
    int rndmNum = (rand() % (max-min+1)) + min;
    return rndmNum;
}
// Will determine the type of Round that will take place
enum ROUNDTYPE getRoundType()
{   
    // declaring roundtype
    enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype; 
    // random number of 1-10
    int max = 10;
    int min = 1;

    int rT = (getRandomNumber(1, 10));
    // conditionals for roundtype

    if (rT <= 2)
    {   
        // Bonus: replace “points” to be equal to 200 as calculated above using a random number generator.
        roundtype = Bonus; 
        printf("\nType    : Bonus");
    }
    else if (rT >= 5)
    {   
        // Regular: keep the “points” equal to the number of points as calculated above using a random number generator.
        roundtype = Regular; 
        printf("\nType    : Regular");
    }
    else
    {   
        // Double: update “points” to be equal to DOUBLE the number of points 
        roundtype = Double; 
        printf("\nType    : Double");
    }
    return roundtype;
}

int getRoundPoints(enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype)
{   
    // points variable
    int points;
    // conditionals to calculate points by roundtype
    if (roundtype == Bonus)
    {
        // print out points (10 - 100) in multiples of 10
        points = 200;
    }
    else if (Double == roundtype)
    {   
        points = getRandomNumber(1, 10) * 20;    
    }
    else
    {
        points = getRandomNumber(1, 10) * 10;
    }
    printf("\nPoints  : %d", points);
    return points; // add to return points
}
/*
void printPlayerPoints( int p1, int p2)
{

}

void printRoundInfo( ROUNDTYPE t, int dice, int points)
{

}
*/
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    printf("%d", getRandomNumber(min, max));

    enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype = getRoundType(); // Store the return value
    getRoundPoints(roundtype); // Pass the roundtype variable

    return 0;
}
```

So this is my code will the suggestions I saw in place I have updated the code and found that I was also missing the return roundtype on getRoundType function. As well as main function changes to store the return value